# add-apt-repository gpg error: keybox created, keyserver receive failed: no data

Tags: gnupg, add-apt-repository, keyserver

I tired to add the `webupd8team/java` PPA using the command below, but got an error by gpg:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

error occured

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp7fgyev7b/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: keyserver receive failed: no data
failed to add key
```

How can I fix this and add the PPA?